# Getting class not found error.original size of apk is 3.4 mb but it get compressed automatically to 1.7 mb

Tags: android

Apk file which is generated is in zip compress format I think because original size is 3.4 MB and it is showing 1.7 MB.I am getting class not found error when I send by email.it is working fine if I install apk directly by computer but getting class not found error when I install by email apk.
I am getting this error 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "asd.abs.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/asd.abs-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Comment: What type of code you have done we don't know because can't see code in question.

Comment: Hello piyush I am only doing new project now.There is nothing into app except hello world text but if i install apk by email then i am getting Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "asd.abs.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/asd.abs-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]].

Comment: I think apk file is getting compressed automatically and can not install by any other source like email skype or xender.It get istalled but getting class not found exception while launch app